# How to notify all instances behind load balancer

Tags: architecture

I would like to make an request to all instances of my application. Flow of request is as follow( F5 load balancer -> reverse proxy - apache server -> my application) I do not want to make public ip endpoint on all instances or create service discovery server if it would not be necessary. Are there any simple solutions that i can use ?

Comment: Welcome to Software Engineering. We only support [good](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions. [Many sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have [different rules](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067). Feel free to take your issue to an appropriate site if one exists. Search existing answers first. Edit your question to fit the sites needs. Please [don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) by failing to delete your question here.

Comment: Consider [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They're more likely to be able to tell you if say [multicast](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K9310) can solve your problem then I am.

Comment: Not sure why the question is getting downvoted. Seems like it's clear enough, and IMO, it's perfectly on-topic here (and moreover reveals a common problem which is often solved wrongly).

Comment: IMO what's missing here is context. *Why* do you need to contact all instances of your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to notify all the instances, use a message queue service.

If, for some reason, you can't do that and should necessarily do it through the reverse proxy, this can be achieved by having a mechanism which allows for the client to target a specific instance, often for the purpose of sticky sessions.

In other words, the request contains some information which indicates to the reverse proxy which one of the instances should the request be redirected to. For instance, the first request of the user doesn't contain any preference, and is redirected to instance *N*. The instance *N* adds a cookie to the response, so that the reverse proxy forwards all successive requests (i.e. the ones which contain the aforementioned cookie) to the same instance, unless the instance is down.

Be careful, however, with this technique:

- One of the goals of a reverse proxy is to abstract away the underlying infrastructure, i.e. the client doesn't need to know whether all requests are served by one, ten or one thousand servers. The mechanism where the underlying server is somehow identified in the request breaks this.
- The case where the specified instance is down should require special attention. What should the reverse proxy do? Respond with an error? Silently fallback to another instance? Wait forever for the instance to come back?
- Sticky sessions make it easier to perform DOS/DDOS attacks by bringing down the instances one by one until there are none left (and is likely to make it easier to know how well the attack is affecting your infrastructure).

For the last point alone, I would strongly advise against sticky sessions: MQS, and not the reverse proxy, is the tool for the task.

Comment: I also think that message queue would be best solution, but there will only be one topic and i am afraid that it will be hard to convince my team to do so.

Comment: The sticky session solution is also interesting, but there are some problems with it .We are already using sticky session, but with session cookie, so we would need to make sticky session configuration more complex and define another cookie that define to which server should this request go. But this is a little dangerous as you pointed out in post above, as they will know how many instances of application are running.

Comment: There is a third solution i came up, and in this solution I will be passing to every instance information about all running instances and first application that will get request will notify other instances. But If i would like to add new instance, then i would need to change configuration of all instances(so they will know about new one)